# want to get the trend in 20 10 5 day historical volatility using Logs but getting negative number

Tags: volatility, python

Ok so I am not a math whizz so need some SERIOUS help here. I have historical volatilities:

20 day historical volatility = 49.07%
10 day historical volatility = 47.43%
5  day historical volatility = 41.77%

My goal is to show the relative change between the following:

the change between the 20 day HV and the 10 day hv = diff2010

the change between the 10 day HV and the 5  day hv = diff105

the overall change of 20 10 5 day = diffabs

I got helpful advice that I should use the log function to get the difference in a mathematically accurate manner using the equation below

log_diff2010 = math.log(10 day hv ) - math.log(20 day hv )

log_diff105 = math.log(5 day hv)  - math.log(10 day hv )

log_diffabs = math.log(log_diff105) - math.log(log_diff2010)

BUT the log_diffabs results in a -ve log num which causes an error.
SO I have two questions:

1 are my calculations for log_diff2010 and log_diff105 correct?

2 how can I find the overall change for the period 20 10 5 day

here is the python 3.5 run where it all goes wrong for me :-(

> > > import math
> > >
> > > math.log(47.43)

```
 3.85925493988949
```

> > > log_diff2010 = math.log(47.43) - math.log(49.07)
> > >
> > > log_diff105 = math.log(41.77) - math.log(47.43)
> > >
> > > log_diffabs = math.log(log_diff105) - math.log(log_diff2010)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
   log_diffabs = math.log(log_diff105) - math.log(log_diff2010)

    ValueError: math domain error

  >>> log_diff105

 -0.12707656138040635

  >>> log_diff2010

-0.03399291021232198
  >>> r2010 = round(log_diff2010,4)

  >>> r105 = round(log_diff105,4)

  >>> r2010

  -0.034

  >>> r105

    -0.1271

   >>> rrabs = math.log(r105) - math.log(r2010)

   Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>


      rrabs = math.log(r105) - math.log(r2010)

   ValueError: math domain error

   >>>
```

Comment: Hmmm, it wasn't exactly helpful advice. If the volatilitys are given as percentages, you would take log(1+vol). If there are given as changes in log price, you can just add and subtract.

Comment: Hi @barrycarter  thanks fot taking an interest in this.  Yep the volatilities are given as a percentage ( sorry for not making that clear).  how would you achieve the comparisons using my example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using exponents / root will solve nagative values

```
import math

log_diff2010 = math.log(47.43) - math.log(49.07)
log_diff105 = (math.log(41.77) - math.log(47.43))
print log_diff105,(log_diff105**2)**.5,(log_diff2010**2)**.5,(log_diff2010**2)**.5
log_diffabs = math.log( (log_diff105**2)**.5) - math.log( (log_diff2010**2)**.5)
print log_diffabs
```

Comment: thanks so much for the answer, I will have to hit the books to find out why this works. Great help BUT I cannot vote it up as I don't have the points. When I do I will come back and fix that. Thanks again I would NEVER have got that answer